# Eclipse java graphics issues

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working in eclipse on creating a canvas that can draw lines or something like that on it, a simple program, I know. I have created a Canvas class, a CartesianCoordinate class, and a main class. I have created a method to draw a line of a specified color on the canvas created, but whenever I try to enter the color, I always get told something is wrong. I've checked and it seems that everything is right, so if someone could help me I'd be very appreciative! Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Lab {
public static void main(String [ ] args){

    CartesianCoordinate myCoordinate;
    myCoordinate = new CartesianCoordinate(300, 400);

    myCoordinate.getX();
    myCoordinate.getY();

    System.out.printf("The coordinates are: (%s)", myCoordinate.toCoord());

    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(800, 600);

    myCanvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(400, 500, green);


 }

}






public class CartesianCoordinate {

private int xPosition;
private int yPosition;

public CartesianCoordinate(int startingX, int startingY){
    this.xPosition = startingX;
    this.yPosition = startingY;
}
    public int getX() {
        return this.xPosition;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.yPosition;
    }
    public String toCoord(){
        return String.format("%02d, %02d", getX(), getY());
    }

}







import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;



public class Canvas extends JPanel {

private int xSize, ySize;
private JPanel panel;
private String frameTitle;
private List<LS> lines;
private final static int DEFAULT_X = 800;
private final static int DEFAULT_Y = 600;


public Canvas() {
    this(DEFAULT_X, DEFAULT_Y);
}


public Canvas(int x, int y) {
    xSize = x;
    ySize = y;
    frameTitle = "Canvas";
    lines = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<LS>());
    setupCanvas();
}

private void setupCanvas() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Basic GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(this.xSize, this.ySize);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);  // Smoother lines
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

    synchronized(lines) {
        for (LS line : lines) {
            g2.setColor(line.getColor());
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), 
                       line.getEndX(), line.getEndY()));
        }
    }
}


public void drawLineBetweenPoints(CartesianCoordinate startPoint, CartesianCoordinate endPoint, String color) {
    lines.add(new LS(startPoint.getX(), startPoint.getY(), 
                              endPoint.getX(), endPoint.getY(),
                              this.parseColour(color)));

    repaint();
}


public void drawLineSegment(LineSegment line, String color) {


    lines.add(new LS(line.getStartPoint().getX(), line.getStartPoint().getY(), 
                     line.getEndPoint().getX(), line.getEndPoint().getY(),
                     this.parseColour(color)));
    repaint();
}


public void drawLineSegments(LineSegment [] lineSegments, String color) {
    for (LineSegment l : lineSegments) {
        lines.add(new LS(l.getStartPoint().getX(), l.getStartPoint().getY(), 
                         l.getEndPoint().getX(), l.getEndPoint().getY(),
                         this.parseColour(color)));
    }
    repaint();
}


private Color parseColour(String colour)
{
    Color drawColor;

    switch (colour.toLowerCase()) {

        case "white":
            drawColor = Color.WHITE;
            break;
        case "black":
            drawColor = Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case "blue":
            drawColor = Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case "cyan":
            drawColor = Color.CYAN;
            break;
        case "gray":
            drawColor = Color.GRAY;
            break;
        case "darkgray":
            drawColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
            break;
        case "lightgray":
            drawColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
            break;
        case "green":
            drawColor = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        case "magenta":
            drawColor = Color.MAGENTA;
            break;
        case "red":
            drawColor = Color.RED;
            break;
        case "orange":
            drawColor = Color.ORANGE;
            break;
        case "yellow":
            drawColor = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown colour '" + colour + "', defaulting        to black.");
            drawColor = Color.BLACK;
            break;
    }


    return drawColor;
}



public void removeMostRecentLine()
{
    this.lines.remove(this.lines.size()-1);
}



public void clear() {
    lines.clear();
    repaint();
}


private class LS {
    private int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    private Color color;


    public LS(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, Color c) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
        this.color = c;
    }


    public int getStartX() {
        return this.startX;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }


    public int getStartY() {
        return this.startY;
    }


    public int getEndX() {
        return this.endX;
    }


    public int getEndY() {
        return this.endY;
    }
}
}
```

According to eclipse, when I type "myCanvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(400, 500, green)", it says that it doesn't recognise the color I specified. I have tried with many colors that I included in the Canvas class, and it still says the same. Am I missing something here? If I am, could someone please direct me towards where my error is? And please don't just say it's because eclipse is bad, it's not that helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I guess `color` that you are passing should be a string not a variable in your case `green`

Comment: Okay, so how do I go about fixing this? I'm sorry if that's a dumb question, but I'm pretty confused...

Comment: Change "myCanvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(400, 500, green);" to "myCanvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(400, 500, "green");"

Comment: When I do so another error message pops up: The method drawLineBetweenPoints(CartesianCoordinate, CartesianCoordinate, String) in the the type Canvas is not applicable for the arguments (int, int String).

Comment: 1) Read the message. Then parameters you are passing to the method don't match the method signature. 2) Don't call your class "Canvas". There is an AWT class by then name which causes confusion. The class name should be more descriptive. 3) You can use the `Point` class instead of creating a CartesianCoordinate class.